# create a customised notification ui for firebase messaging in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to create a custom notification ui in flutter for firebase messaging, while in background.

something like having an action button in the notification, to do a specific thing.

i tried to do it with flutter_local_notification,
and i was able to show the custom notification successfully.

but i can't hide the built-in notification that comes from the firebase background handler from package itself and now i have both the notifications shown for every request like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak8jc.png)

the first notification with "new" action at the bottom is my custom one that came from the flutter_local_notifications
package

and the second one came from the default firebase messaging package handler

I'm using the firebase console to send my messages

i tried to create a function that shows a custom local notification and pass it to Firebase.

`FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_showLocalNotification)`

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Messages sent through Firebase Cloud Messaging can have [two main sections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) that determine how they are handled:

- If a message contains a `notification` section:

  - If the user is not actively using the app, that notification will be handled/displayed by the system. There is no way to suppress/change this behavior.
  - If the user is actively using the app, the message will be delivered to your application code.
- If the message contains a `data` section, it will be delivered to your application code.

So if you don't want the system to ever display the message, you need to ensure that it does **not** contain a `notification` section. I.e. sending a `data`-only message ensures it's always handled by *your* code, and you can use it to display your custom, local notification.